# Admin SDK does not retrieve full profile information

Tags: google-plus, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I am developing an application that extracts Google Apps domain user information using the Admin SDK. 
I want to gather all data (in particular phones) that appear in the Directory profile of domain users in the Apps contacts list.
The domain users have some extra information like phones and addresses coming from the G+ profile that are showed in the contacts detail, but I'm not able to retrieve these data using:

- Google+ API v1 > plus.people.get
- Admin Directory API directory_v1 > directory.users.list o directory.users.get

In both cases the phones are not returned in the JSON.

I have tried to insert a phone using directory.user.patch, and then queried the user with directory.users.get: this time the phone is returned in the JSON. Maybe it is stored in a different place?

So my question is: is there a way/API to get all G+ profile data without patching all the users with the additional info?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's currently possible to pull this data via the APIs. The Google+ profile info is kept separate from what's pulled with the Directory API and the G+ APIs don't pull contact details from what I can see.

Comment: Thanks, that was my concern too. Can we have an official answer form any googler working at those APIs?

Comment: Asked someone on the team to take a look :)